# Store username password in browser's localstorage using c#

Tags: asp.net, security, local-storage

I'm developing a mobile oriented website using asp.net. This website will consume some web services requiring username and password to be send for each call. For this, I will need to store the credential that the user will use on the login form, on the client. What are the best practices?

I wonder how I should save the username and password locally keeping an acceptable level of security.

I was thinking about encrypting the credentials in C# and then store the encrypted value in the localStorage of the browser. Would it be "secured" ?

Other question, is it possible to store in the localStorage using C# to trigger JavaScript?

Thanks.

Comment: Why not use session state? User logs in, get a cookie and use that cookie with a sessionID to authenticate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't do it would be the best practice.

Seriously, malware on mobile devices is so high these days, I wouldn't store anything sensitive on them.  Plus it's very easy to lose a mobile device, and then who's going to have the login info?

Even on normal websites, there's usually a "remember me" option and it's up to the USER to determine if they want to save it if they want, not the web developer.

In the case of a "rememberer me" checkbox, the user's credentials are usually stored in a cookie.  Not the most secure thing in the world.  http://www.wisegeek.com/is-it-safe-to-select-the-remember-me-on-this-computer-checkbox-with-online-accounts.htm

Some websites use a Windows login or something similar, where there's an actual login prompt, and that's all handled by the browser, again, not by the web developer.

If you were developing a true mobile app, THEN it would be up to you to store the password securely.  But not for a mobile website.

Comment: Thanks for this clear answer!

So how should I do knowing that the web services need the username and the password in the request?

Comment: I would soften this a bit if there were absolutely no sensitive data in the app, and you just want to remember the user for things like keeping their preferred city for a weather app, etc.  Completely harmless data.  But if you're giving them access to anything that a malicious user could turn to profit, then I'd strongly argue against even providing a mechanism for remembering the login of the user.  Lost/stolen mobile devices are a growing source of data breach entry points.

Comment: The client on the mobile device doesn't NEED the username password.  the website needs the username/password if the website is making the calls to the web service.  The device should be completely unaware of it.  or am I reading this wrong?  Your web site runs on a server, and the server-side code is what's calling the web service, not the client app, right?

Comment: Ok, I'm gonna investigate in this way. Thanks!